# TYPO3 - How to Create a System Folder page

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 4.5.2 ; I want to create a a System Folder page for "" as see in these documentation  http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/extension-manuals/sr_feuser_register/2.5.4/view/1/4/, but I don't know how.

Can one help ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the *SysFolder* has been renamed to *Folder* in TYPO3 4.5. You can make a page of type Folder by editing the page properties and changing the *Type* field (the first one in the form).